# Display only contacts with right phone number (Contacts Framework)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, contacts

I want to display only those contacts with particular phone numbers. The phone numbers are written in an array. I don't know how to display only these contacts. Therefore I tried to use the "predicateForEnablingContact" Method.
But with my code, all contacts are disabled, even the ones with the right number. I am using the Contacts Framework. Help would be much appreciated.

```
func picker () {
    let numbers = ["555","8885555512"]
    let pick = CNContactPickerViewController()
    pick.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
   pick.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers = %@", argumentArray: numbers)
    pick.delegate = self
    presentViewController(pick, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]) {
    let Kontakte = contacts
    print(Kontakte)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: `phoneNumbers` is not an array of numbers, so it will never match your `numbers` array. You need to think about what "with particular phone numbers" really means to you.

Comment: I want to make a chat app and to display only the contacts, which use the app. I thought i could do that by downloading the user number from parse and use this number to search the contacts. But it should work if I search the contacts phonenumbers on parse, then download the name if it exists and then use the Predicate with the name or is this wrong too?

Comment: "to display only the contacts, which use the app" The identifier for a contact is its `identifier`.

Comment: Here's my answer, hope this may help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481483/how-to-filter-contacts-using-a-set-of-phone-numbers-with-cncontactpickerviewcont/53574432#53574432>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns only the contacts that have a phone number in the given set:

```
let numbers = Set(["555","8885555512"])

let predicate = NSPredicate { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
    guard let evaluatedContact = evaluatedObject as? CNContact else { return false }
    return Set(evaluatedContact.phoneNumbers.map{ return ($0.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue }).intersect(numbers).count > 0
}
```

Note that `numbers` is a Set. This is in order to use the `intersect` method later on. `intersect` is used to determine if the contact shares any phone numbers with the given numbers; if so, then the predicate results in `true`.

Comment: @FredA. For most of the Contacts framework that is true, but if you check the CNContactPickerViewController docs, it doesn't say you can't.

Comment: Have you tried this ? Because I have, and it doesn't work ... Also, the doc says: "Note that generic and compound predicates are not supported by the Contacts framework"

Comment: @FredA. I use a similar implementation in my app that excludes based on Contact ID number, and it works well. If you want to try it out, it's called Contact Archiver. Press Select Contacts, choose a few, then press select again and the contacts in the picker are disabled.

Comment: The predicate is correct but `NSBlockPredicate` cannot be used with `predicateForEnablingContact` on `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [KPKContacts](https://github.com/pavankataria/KPKContacts) package

Its as simple as calling this method

```
var contacts: [KPKContact]()
let contactStore = KPKContactStore()
//make sure you implement the delegate method that will notify contact authorisation changes
contactStore.delegate = self

self.kpkContactStore.findContactsWithValidNumbersOnly(){
    kpkContacts in
    if let contacts = kpkContacts {
        self.contacts = contacts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It comes with a default regex to phone numbers formatted as ### ### ###, ###-###-###, (###) ###-####, #-###-###-###, ###-###-###, #########

You can alternatively get your own regex from regex resources and edit the PHONE_REGEX property in this method

```
private var regexPhoneNumberValidatorBlock: String -> Bool = { value in
let PHONE_REGEX = "^\\s*(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\\d{3})[-. )]*(\\d{3})[-. ]*(\\d{4})(?: *x(\\d+))?\\s*$"
    let phoneTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", PHONE_REGEX)
    let result =  phoneTest.evaluateWithObject(value)
    return result
}
```